# Should i use static lock object or instance object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working with an asp.net webapi program (not .net core). there is a class that has read/write files function. in order to keep the thread-safe, I want to add a lock.

someone suggest below code:

```
private static readonly object Locker = new object();
```

And someone suggests I should use an instance locker.  which is correct? what's the scope of the locker?

if the program creates multiple instances, will the locker still work?

Or should I make this class Singleton?

Comment: The lock should correspond to the resource that is shared. If there are multiple instances but they all write to the same files, the lock must be static.

Comment: You're looking for one answer to a question that is situation dependent. If you were making a thread-safe generic collection, you wouldn't want a static lock object, as all instances would depend on the same lock. In Rotem's example, you'd probably want a static lock.